# Create Dynamic VO Object And LOV and set groovy for value In Oracle ADF Model

Tags: java, groovy, oracle-adf

I created dynamic view run time and I have one transient field. I created LOV for this transient field and fill both this field and another from LOV view object. In edit mode i need to load LOV value in transient field. i crate groovy and set related AttributeDef like this:

```
int clmnIndex = newView.getAttributeIndexOf(lovColumnName);
AttributeDefImpl _voAttrDef = (AttributeDefImpl)newView.getAttributeDef(clmnIndex);
_voAttrDef.setRecalcExpression("true");
_voAttrDef.setTransientExpression(getGroovyFindByKey());
_voAttrDef.setLOVName(lovName);
_voAttrDef.setProperty(AttributeHints.ATTRIBUTE_CTL_TYPE, AttributeHints.CTLTYPE_LOV);
newView.resolveDefObject();
newView.registerDefObject();

private String getGroovyFindByKey(){
     String groovy = "test";
    return groovy;
}
```

But above dynamic configuration that we create in code won`t execute my groovy when I load data in UI.

What I must do additional to this API calls to enable run-time execution of my groovy codes.